# Custom REST API Call with jQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jquery datatables with the custom rest api for fetching records from the server with pagination and sorting. My response of json is

```
{
    "total": "0",
    "data": [data here]
}
```

I don't want to restrict my API to send me response for count as "iTotalRecords" which datatable plugin requires in order to show pagination. Is there any way to customize it on the response or before the table is populated ?

Comment: So what do you want exactly? Please describe a little bit further. iTotalRecords does not restrict your api, its just a value that dataTables need to display some info after the ajax call has been done.

Comment: The datatable expects iTotalRecords from json response but my rest api is returning a field with "total" so how to change that ?

Answer (score 0):

Do changes to the received data in the fnServerData callback:

```
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "xhr.php",
    "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {
      oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
        "dataType": 'json',
        "type": "POST",
        "url": sSource,
        "data": aoData,
        "success": function(aoData){
            aoData.iTotalRecords=aoData.total;
            fnCallback (aoData);
            }
      } );
    }
  });
```

Not sure if this works for your data. Can't verify also since i'm not at my office. But this should give you a hint on how to proceed.